# Remove character codes from output

Tags: python

My CSV has lines like this:

```
ID,Subject,Body
```

When I read it with with Python's csv library and output a row using

`print row`

I get:

```
(bytearray(b'ID'), bytearray(b'Subject'), bytearray(b'Body'))
```

Any way to get rid of all the extraneous information and just output the original text?

Comment: read your file in text mode (with optional encoding)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal